# How to create multiple apps from same shared code in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm developing 2 different apps that share 95% of the same code and views. What is the best way to go about this using Xcode?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use targets. That's exactly what they are for.

[Learn more about the concept of targets here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Targets.html).

Typically, the majority of projects have a single Target, which corresponds to one product/application. If you define multiple targets, you can:

- include some of your source code files (or maybe all) in both targets, some in one target and some in the other
- you can play with Build Settings to compile the two targets using different settings.

---

For example you may define Precompiler Macros for one target and other macros for the other (let's say `OTHER_C_FLAGS = -DPREMIUM` in target "PremiumVersion" and `OTHER_C_FLAGS = -DLITE` to define the `LITE` macro in the "LiteVersion" target) and then include similar code in your source:

```
-(IBAction)commonCodeToBothTargetsHere
{
   ...
}

-(void)doStuffOnlyAvailableForPremiumVersion
{
#if PREMIUM
   // This code will only be compiled if the PREMIUM macro is defined
   // namely only when you compile the "PremiumVersion" target
   .... // do real stuff
#else
   // This code will only be compiled if the PREMIUM macro is NOT defined
   // namely when you compile the "LiteVersion" target

   [[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Only for premium" 
       message:@"Sorry, this feature is reserved for premium users. Go buy the premium version on the AppStore!"
       delegate:self
       cancelButtonTitle:@"Doh!"
       otherButtonTitles:@"Go buy it!",nil]
   autorelease] show];
#endif
}

-(void)otherCommonCodeToBothTargetsHere
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: If you're accustomed to it, think of targets as different makefiles. They have the same role.

Comment: This is huge, thank you.  To get this to really work right for me I needed to do a copy target then update the target settings to use a different Info.plist for my bundle name ect...

Comment: Note that if you further add files to your project, be careful to add the file to both targets and not only the active one: when adding the file, in the dialog that appears to ask if you want to copy files or not etc, you have a list of your targets and checkboxes in front of each one. (The checkboxes state is saved so that you will probably need to check this only once anyway)