# Multiple Xcode targets in a single upload

Tags: ios, xcode

I learnt that for creating multiple apps using almost same code, we can use [multiple targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454946/how-to-create-multiple-apps-from-same-shared-code-in-xcode), which is really great. So assuming there are multiple targets, we have to publish all the apps separately. Is it possible to upload all the apps (targets) in one go?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Targets.html said that A target specifies a product to build and contains the instructions for building the product from a set of files in a project or workspace. A target defines a single product; it organizes the inputs into the build system—the source files and instructions for processing those source files—required to build that product. Projects can contain one or more targets, each of which produces one product.

Answer (score 0):

Developers mostly create a new target as they want to upload a app which is almost same but having fewer changes which can be managed by macro.
And also when you create a new target at that stage a new scheme will be created so that you can compile and run specific app. Considering this scenario you have to select specific target, scheme and then you can upload each and every application individually.