# Most efficient method of developing/maintaining a "Lite" and "Pro" version of an app

Tags: ios, xcode, github

Over the past few years, I have been developing/maintaining a Lite and Pro version of an app. I do this by developing new features for the Pro version, and then duplicating this project, renaming all of the attributes in the Pro version to reflect the Lite version's attributes (app name, bundle identifier, etc.). Although they do share a lot of the same code (I'd say about 90% of the app); however, they do have minor differences: for eg. the Lite version is light, whereas the Pro version has more of a darker, 'professional' look to it. Another example would be something like the Lite version having an "Upgrade" button, whereas the Pro version will have multiple buttons that actually have functions.

TL;DR: I have two versions of an app, a Lite and a Pro version. They share 90% of the same code, but have minor differences (like theme colours and different buttons with different functions).

What is the best way to go about maintaining a Lite and a Pro version of an app to optimize for maximum efficiency? (Specifically in Xcode, if you feel like getting into detail). I do use GitHub as well, so possibly a method using branches?

Comment: Just out of the blue, why not have a single "master" project where you do all your works, and just set a global define to wether it is the pro or the lite version, and just export the code to the correct project when you are ready for upload to App Store, without the need to do any modifications.

Comment: One project, two targets.

Comment: @rmaddy Even better, upvoted.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454946/how-to-create-multiple-apps-from-same-shared-code-in-xcode

Comment: @rmaddy or one target, two xcconfig files